# AWS Instance LDAP 389 not able to access in internet

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created an AWS EC2 instance of type t2.micro. Then installed Microsoft active directory and it's working fine inside the instance. I tried to access this LDAP server for single sign-on with node.js application but port 389 is not able to access outside (internet) instance.

In SecurityGroups I've updated the inbound enable the LDAP 389 port and source set to 0.0.0.0/0 and even I have enabled the elastic IP but still not working. 
[image]

Comment: Did you create this Instance in Private Subnet?

Comment: @error2007s sorry I dont know how is created.. I'm new to aws please give me some idea what is private subnet... it will easy for me to answer